# jQuery valiator (Custom method error message)

Tags: jquery, validation

I've written a custom method to validate my forms. (Checks that the input doesn't match the default text, also title of input element)

```
$.validator.addMethod("default_text", function(value, element){
    return (element.title === value) ? false : true;
}, "Custom error message."),
```

For some reason my output is the title of the field rather than the "custom error message" is there something important that I'm missing out or am I defining the error message incorrectly.

Appreciate all help :)

Regards

*Just to note the method works as I require it to, just the error message only shows the input title rather than the error message*

Comment: Simplify your code: return (element.title !== value);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery Validator uses the `title` property if it is defined, so you can't define a title attribute to your input. Use a custom attribute.

Check the docs: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

> **messages** (default: the default message for the method used)
>   Type: Object
>   Key/value pairs defining custom messages. Key is the name of an element, value the message to display for that element. Instead of a plain message another map with specific messages for each rule can be used. Overrides the title attribute of an element or the default message for the method (in that order). Each message can be a String or a Callback. The callback is called in the scope of the validator and with the rule’s parameters as the first and the element as the second arugment, it must return a String to display as the message.